# Apache Nifi Read Configuration properties in processor

Tags: java, apache-nifi

Can we read the properties set in nifi.properties in our custom processors?
Eg:
If we add a custom property 
nifi.active.profile = dev/qa

and read its value in the custom processor?

Or while starting NIFI pass arguements, which we can later read

Answer (score 6):

you can use `nifi.variable.registry.properties` parameter in `nifi.properties` to define custom properties file(s)

for example:

```
nifi.variable.registry.properties=./conf/custom.properties
```

and all properties defined in `custom.properties` you could access in nifi expression language.

if you have

```
nifi.active.profile=dev
```

then you can access it in [nifi expression language](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html):

```
${nifi.active.profile}
```

returns `dev`

```
${nifi.active.profile:toUpper()}
```

returns `DEV`

Comment: how can we read integer values from property file using ${batchSize}

Comment: see the [toNumber() function in the nifi expression language](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#tonumber). should be like this: `${batchSize:toNumber()}`

Comment: @dagett, thanks for your helping.    ${batchSize:toNumber()} is not worked. how can we resolve the same

Comment: 'Max Wait Time' validated against '${pool:toNumber()} is invalid because Must be of format <duration><TimeUnit> where <duration> is a non-negative integer and TimeUnit is a supported Time Unit, such as:nanos, millis, secs

Comment: better to ask a new question. because your problem is not clear.

Comment: ${batchSize:toNumber()} this was not worked. In the GetFile processor, it shows the below error message , 'Batch Size' validated against '${batchSize:toNumber()}' is invalid, because not a valid integer

Comment: means batchSize contains not a number (empty value - not a number for example...)

Comment: In the config.properties file has numeric value for the batchSize, but when we are giving the ${batchSize:toNumber()} in the GetFile's processor property value, the above error message is thrown

Comment: This is ${input_directory} working for string property or input directory path in GetFile processor, not working for numeric property in GetFile like 'batchSize'