# Configure Apache NiFi process endpoints via separate configuration

Tags: apache-nifi

My environment contains two separate and independent setups. My development environment runs all software on a VM with everything being local. Either using localhost or my internal IP address. My production environment runs with everything being in a pod. Each having a hostname.

Currently when I create a template from my development environment and move it to my production, I have to go through all the processes and change the endpoints so that it will continue to run and process.

Is there a method in NiFi, that I can define the endpoints on the system that contains the NiFi service, that the processes can rely on to get the proper value for the endpoints. I can move the templates between my development and production and visa-versa without having to reconfigure each process?

Thank you.

Comment: https://pierrevillard.com/2018/04/09/automate-workflow-deployment-in-apache-nifi-with-the-nifi-registry/

Comment: NiFi parameterization. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44605954/apache-nifi-read-configuration-properties-in-processor